# Stop showing server software version information on 404

Tags: security, http-status-code-404

e.g. if someone type url that dont exist it shows 404 page and on bottom

**Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at india.decon.itndevelopment.com Port 80**

i want to remove that line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your Apache configuration:

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
```

For more information, see the documentation for [`ServerSignature`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serversignature) and [`ServerTokens`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servertokens).